# how to create laravel project with docker 2021?

Tags: laravel, docker

Help me childs and in advance excuseme for my English. I want to create a laravel project with docker. I have already installed docker and set wsl 2, and this work. But when continue with the tutorial of the laravel web page, I must put this code..above image
[image]

but I dont know where I must to run this code. I runned it in the windows terminal an appear this..
[image]

what should I do to create the project? What should i put in the uri?

Comment: as the docs said run this command through WSL2 you can search for it to how install it and use it in windows

Comment: thank you for anser TEFO, COULD you explian me step to step that I should do. thank you

Comment: Step one, go to laravel install docs. Step two go to get started in windows. Step three there is red like click them and read them step by step. Step four have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple bash script to run the laravel project with docker, first of all, You must install docker and also you can check the bash script to find out what is really going on in it. I suggest you that use it in linux instead of windows. Use an Ubuntu for your convenience.

Comment: thank you for anser, COULD you explian me step to step that I should do. thank you